# Foreign Key Constraint fails

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

I have the following tables:

```
// Base Scans
CREATE TABLE `basescans` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `status_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `status_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`status_id`) REFERENCES `statuses` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT
AUTO_INCREMENT=29

// Statuses
CREATE TABLE `statuses` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT
AUTO_INCREMENT=4
```

Trying to save the first table fails when I put in that foreign key constraint. Can't figure out why. Both of the columns referenced in the constraint have the same type, size, etc:

```
INT(10) UNSIGNED NULL
```

They only have a difference default value. One has a default value of NULL, the other is AUTO_INCREMENT.  I didn't think that made a difference for foreign key constraints but I could be wrong.

Both tables are InnoDB and UFT8. What am I missing here?

UPDATED: My specific error:

```
/* SQL Error (1452): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-31c2_22ac1e1'>, CONSTRAINT `status_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`status_id`) REFERENCES `statuses` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE) */
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have already declared the table that the foreign key references, before you can define a foreign key that references it.

Once you declare the second table, you can then declare the first table.  Tested [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/deacd) on MySQL 5.5.27.

If you *need* to bypass the validation, you can do this:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
-- declare tables
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks

Comment: Both tables already exist. The above code is the create table code. I'm just trying to add the foreign key.

Comment: Are there any null values in `statuses`.`id`?  Are there any values in `basescans`.`status_id` that don't exist in `statuses`.`id`?

Comment: Ah that was the problem. I guess now that I read the error message about failing on a child row instead of the actual constraint relationship itself, it makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Using query 1 and 2 for drop your table

1) SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

2) DROP TABLE TableName;

Here the TableName, which table you want to drop

Comment: Who said anything about dropping a table?

Comment: Sorry,But this answer is usefull for some users.

Comment: I mean, it doesn't look that way...